# When calling microsoft graph api, I get exception AADB2C90086: The supplied grant_type [client_credentials] is not supported

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to delete a user from my AD B2C directory like so:

```
public static async Task<bool> DeleteUserAsync2(string userId)
{
    var clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Globals.ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(Globals.ClientSecret)
        .WithRedirectUri(Globals.RedirectUri)
        .WithB2CAuthority(Globals.B2CAuthority)
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(clientapp);

    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

    try
    {
        await graphClient.Users[userId]
            .Request()
            .DeleteAsync();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not sure why I am getting this not supported error because this is similar to what my code uses when signing in or signing up users in my application.

Comment: The grant_type = client_credential flow is used only when an application is trying to authenticate itself to AAD and trying to get a token from AAD for itself. When a user tries to authenticate itself and tries to get a token from AAD, you would have to use the Authorization Code Grant flow of OAuth. You can find [more details about this flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).

Answer (score 2):

Because **Azure AD B2C** **does not support** the Client Credential Flow, we must sign in with a user when using Azure AD B2C. [Client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) can be used for **Azure AD**.

Azure AD B2C supports [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) and [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/implicit-flow-single-page-application).

Code samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples#single-page-apps

Comment: thanks pamela. While I have you here, I can't find any API to enforce/enable/disable MFA settings for individual user. Is it true that this doesn't exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "enforce/enable/disable MFA settings"? There are [Microsoft Graph API operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations) that are supported for the management of Azure AD B2C resources. And the code sample about Asp.Net MVC [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C).

Comment: i mean ability to enforce/enable MFA for a particular user or set of users. Portal allows us to do this via the UI, but there's no API

Comment: I am using that same MVC sample but I would like to be able to update/delete users using the API using client credential flow because I want the app to be able to do that on behalf of a system admin. So I don't think the auth code flow will work for me.

Comment: You could use [ropc flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow). Client credential flow is not supported exactly.  And There's no API to enable MFA, both [user flow and custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) can be used for it.

Comment: Yes but the user flow and custom policy apply to the whole B2C directory (all users) as I understand it. I would like my application to be able to enable/disable MFA for a particular set of users on the fly.

Comment: Yes, if you set it in user flow or custom policy, it will apply to all users. You could use "Multi-Factor Authentication" button to set MFA for the specific user that shown in the **user list**.

Comment: You mean using the portal UI? I would like to be able to do this from within my application.

Comment: Yes, only in the portal. No method of SDK and no API for it. You could upvote the feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20560954-allow-mfa-to-be-enabled-for-selected-set-of-b2c-us)